# Reading from File Containing Int and Char data types

Tags: c++

I'm using Dev C++ for this programming assignment.

I'll try and give a basic rundown of the problem...

I'm trying to write a program that will read a time stamp and temperature reading from a file, then put the time stamp in a specific format and convert temperature to Celsius if needed.  The input file has a sentinel number at the top of the file to tell how many lines of data need to be read.  After this single int, each line then contains a number (ie. 200103121915 F51.13), there is a single space between the date and temp.  The format is for YYYYMMDDHHMM.  Without using pointers or any object oriented programming, we are supposed to convert each entry into a MM/DD/YYYY HHMM format and if the temperature is given in Fahrenheit, it needs to be converted to Celsius.

I'm running into problems with every approach I've tried.  First, I was just going to read the entire 12 digit number as an int and then use some modulus commands to separate out each part.  However, I found that int won't hold a number that large.  Next, I thought to read each digit into an array and then piece together the individual arrays into the correct format.  I don't know how to read in one digit at a time.  I was thinking the array would need to be and int type, but then how would I deal with the F or C label?  Basically I'm just looking for some basic ideas on how to accomplish this task, not asking for someone to write the code.

Comment: C++ is not my primary language, but I would read each field in as a string. I am assuming that this is a text based file. See this [link](http://www.bgsu.edu/departments/compsci/docs/read.html)

Comment: This string idea looks very promising for accomplishing the formatting portion of the assignment.  Thanks for the link!  For the temperature reading, though, would there be a way to perform a calculation on the numerical part of the data?

Comment: What's preventing you from using a long long instead of an int?

Comment: It's my understanding that a long long is can only hold 10 digits, but I may be mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just getting started with I/O in C++, you might bookmark a reference site, because the library provides a lot of options and features.

- [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) is a non-authoritative but handy source, wiki-style.
- [Cay Horstmann](http://www.horstmann.com/cpp/streams.txt) wrote an article which covers more ground, and you can search for key words.
- [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/) has fairly good coverage of older language features, but has a few errors and isn't well updated.

As a further pointer, the `std::setw` manipulator might help to extract a given number of characters — although it won't stop numeric extraction from being too greedy.

Comment: Thanks for the great links, I've already bookmarked these for future use!  I think I've finally gotten my code heading in the right direction.  I'll post it when it's finished.

Comment: `setw` doesn't affect numeric extraction, does it?  The only functions it does affect, seem to require a pointer, which was forbidden by the problem constraints :(

Comment: @BenVoigt: Indeed, checking §22.4.2.1.2/3 "Phase 2", the field width is not mentioned! So it is necessary to read the characters into an intermediate buffer, perhaps under the control of `setw`. (What a mess.)

Answer (score 1):

This would be MUCH easier just using the old-school stdio.h functions.

```
fscanf(stream, "%4d%2d%2d%2d%2d %c%f", &year, &month, &mday, &hour, &minute, &unit, &temp);
```

If you really really really can't use pointers, then

```
year = 1000 * (fgetc(stream) - '0');
year += 100 * (fgetc(stream) - '0');
year +=  10 * (fgetc(stream) - '0');
year +=       (fgetc(stream) - '0');
month =  10 * (fgetc(stream) - '0');
month+=       (fgetc(stream) - '0');
```

and so on...